# HTTP POST to Yii2

Tags: http, post, request, yii2

I'm using Postman ( Chrome extension ) to POST data to my Yii2 application.

I have a method in my SiteController:

```
public function actionMobileLogin()
{
    echo "MobileLogin";
    var_dump($_POST);
}
```

When I do post to: [my website]/web?r=site/mobile-login

I get as response only:

```
MobileLoginarray(0) {
}
```

I tried to do POST to other php file with same PHP code ( a file that not extends class Controller ), everything is working fine. The problem appears when I do post to a Yii2 action.

What I need to do to receive POST to my Yii2 methods from external Server ?

Comment: Check your url `[my website]/web?r=site/mobile-login` on browser. Maybe we have a redirect.

Comment: The problem was that I need to do POST to [my website]/web/?r=site/mobile-login. I don't know difference between POST to /web?r=... and /web/?r=...

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is too late, but you have to override the next attribute in your controller:

```
public  $enableCsrfValidation = false;
```

Comment: can you explain more? It may help me. Thanks

Comment: This one should be taken as a correct answer to the question above. You have only to add that line to the recieving controller public  $enableCsrfValidation = false; and all contained actions in the controller would accessible from external links.